# can we create an ec2 image using terraform by ami name created packer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, packer

I am trying my hands on terraform and packer.

I have created a costume image with packer.

I know we can create an image with ami id.
I have tried:

```
resource "aws_instance" "packer-yellowpages" {

  ami = "*******"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  tags ={
      Name  = "demo"
  }
}
```

I was wondering if we can do the same with ami name?

the reason I am thinking about this is: I read somewhere that cloud provider scrap the AMI id. So is there a way I can do this some other way apart from id.
OR implement some storage plan to access the store and access the image?

Answer (score 1):

The [aws_ami data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html) can be used to fetch information on an AMI based on tags such as "name".

```
data "aws_ami" "example" {
  executable_users = ["self"]
  most_recent      = true
  owners           = ["self"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["myami-*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "packer-yellowpages" {

  ami = data.aws_ami.example.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  tags ={
      Name  = "demo"
  }
}
```

Comment: i am not trying it in a right way as i am getting a error "query return no value"

my current ami name is "yellowpages". where i need to substitute that get the result.
i assume self is a key work here 
sorry for my elementary knowledge

Comment: @sumanthshetty replace `myami-*` with `yellowpages`

Comment: still getting same error 

data "aws_ami" "example" {
  executable_users = ["self"]
  most_recent      = true
  owners           = ["self"]

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["yellow-pages"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "yellowpages" {

  ami = data.aws_ami.example.id
  instance_type = "t3.micro"
  key_name = "*******"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-*********"]
  tags ={
      Name  = "yellowpages"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these instead to see if it works?

```
data "aws_ami" "example" {
  executable_users = ["self"]
  most_recent      = true
  owners           = ["self"]
  name_regex       = "yellowpages"
}
```

It may be `AMI Name`, not `Name` tag.